# Alternatives to setting up an API system

Tags: api, api-design, web-api, cookies

I want to launch a service that could support integration by third-parties. Unfortunately it’s way out of hand to build an entire API by now. Here’s my question: Would there be any possible solution by providing cookie access to third-parties in the browser by the logged in user? For example, “like a picture” in the name of the user (login session in cookie) and I would just have to write a server script gateway to formerly ask the user for permission and legitimate the requestion. This would basically be cross-platform, cross-browser and would work as API openly accessible to everyone disregard registering for an app or not. Could such a thing be possible? Any security damage I might **not be able to solve at all?**

Comment: Facebook does something similar(though much more elaborated than what you have in mind) - take a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.5

Comment: @IdanArye this still uses APP IDS unfortunately. Isn't there any other way to hijack the session cookie purposely and simply give post parameters to the developers or something alike?